# Why won't pytest use pyproject.toml for this deprecation warning

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django, pyproject.toml

I have a django project managed with pytest and poetry.

I'd like to put my pytest config into the `pyproject.toml` file, so I added:

```
[tool.pytest]
filterwarnings = ["ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango40Warning", "ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango41Warning"]
```

However, this made no difference - the warning weren't filtered.

If I add a pytest.ini file containing the following...

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango40Warning
    ignore::django.utils.deprecation.RemovedInDjango41Warning
```

... it works just fine.

What's wrong with my `pyproject.toml`, or my pytest configuration, that it's not being picked up?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As per [pytest's docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#pyproject-toml) the section name should be `[tool.pytest.ini_options]`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I was working off a github issue form when pyproject support was initially implemented, it must have been from before they reserved the [tool.pytest] for future use.

Thanks again!